# TDD - Unit Testing a Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a class with the responsibility of calling a web service and returning a result.

I am unit testing the entire framework using NUnit but in this case I can't find any compelling reasons why this would constitute a good unit test

**Why?**

- When the web service returns data, it is indeterminate; that is, *x* may not always result in *y*
- When the web service does not return any data, 404 not found occurs

**Examples:**

```
Result res = GetServiceData("783462"); // Could return x, y or 404 not found.
Result res = GetServiceData("444444"); // Could return x, y or 404 not found.
```

This therefore does not seem like something that can credibly be unit tested...

How might one find compelling reasons to unit test such a class, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Right now you're presenting the question as if you want to unit test the actual downloading of the data. Is that what you want to test?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel well I want to test that it either returns data, or an exception (404 not found) is thrown, but since either could happen for any test data, I'm not sure how I would go about testing this. Equally it seems silly to test something that will have one of two outcomes without actually observing the metrics for each outcome (if that makes sense?)

Comment: Aka: it will always return data or an exception, so why would you want to test this? Leave that up to whoever maintains the web service. You don't have to test what their system does, you test yours.

Comment: In general, I wouldn't worry about unit testing the calling of external APIs/libraries unless you are unit testing your own handling of those calls.  E.g. if you were wanting to ensure you handled 404 responses correctly, craft a nonsensical request that is sure to return 404 and unit test your handling of that response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing the web service, in an integrated fashion, you are not unit testing. You are integration testing.

Is there value in integration testing? Certainly, but you have to control the data, which means part of your job is to set up the data that is pulled so you get something that can be tested. What purpose does this serve? In some cases, none, but if the data passes through business rules, it can be very valuable. In fact, you can set up a matrix of acceptance conditions and see that the entire system meets the acceptance criteria. That adds value.

There is also some value, in your particular instance, of making sure a 404 is present when you ask for data that cannot be there (for example, test with a negative number?).

If you only want to test the unit, you need to inject the dependencies so you are only testing the code. Is there value in that? It depends. If it is merely a pass through type of service (ie, all the work done by a class library), you are only verifying Microsoft did their job on the framework, which usually has limited value, if any.